# Examples on using a HWND from C# UserControl in via DirectShow in C++

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, command-line-interface

Does anybody have any simple examples on how to provide C++ code a window that can be used for DirectShow rendering from a C# UserControl?

I am currently able to create a separate and render to a window via a WS_POPUP window and match its size/position to the existing control window I have reserved for the video pane on the WPF control.

As soon as I try to make the window a child of the WPF control or set WS_CHILD on a new or existing window everything stops rendering and I receive no error explaining what is going on.

Ideally I would be able to pass existing HWND from C# through to the C++/DirectShow class and use it there as-is.

P.S.

Before you ask "Why don't you just... do something different", I need to control DirectShow from C++ and have to display the results via a C# (WPF) control.  I have no control over these conditions.

C#/WPF (control reserved)  <--->  C++/CLI  <--->  C++/HWND/DirectShow

Comment: Really? Nothing?  No suggestions?  Basically everything works unless I attempt to use a HWND that I don't create manually or if I set the parent of a created HWND to one that I don't create manually.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of achieving this would be to use VMR in the windowless mode. The following snippet of code illustrates this(This is for working code. I have removed error checks etc but should give you an idea):

```
    pVMRConfig->SetRenderingMode(VMRMode_Windowless);
    m_VMR->QueryInterface(IID_IVMRWindowlessControl9, (void**)&pVMRWindowlessControl);

    //displayWnd is what you pass in from your C# app
    pVMRWindowlessControl->SetVideoClippingWindow(displayWnd); 
    RECT rcDest;
    GetClientRect(displayWnd, &rcDest); 
    hr = pVMRWindowlessControl->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &rcDest);
```